# TestFlight Integration Query

Tags: ios, testflight

I have 2 developer account

1) My Company
2) Client Company

I know that for testing and beta release I have to load my `.ipa` in iTunes connect. [I am following this tutorial.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133121/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing)

I have following query

1) Should I have to upload the beta test version in the Client Company apple developer account as it need to be live using his developer account?

2) Does the beta version wait to be live before going for test if so how much time it takes?

3) Any best way to integrate Test flight without iTunes connect (As past 3 years back test flight used to upload `.ipa` from its website and easily to distribute)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a client's developer account then do everything on it.

1. Yes, do it on client's account. If you do it on your company's account then you will also have to create the application on your account and at the time of submission you will have to redo all steps of application creation in clients's account.
2. If the testers are internal then no, otherwise yes.
3. No but you can speed up the process of build submission on Testflight and distribution using [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane).

Answer (score 1):

1. ? Don't understand your question; it's better to download build from that account, where you probably distribute your app
2. For external testing it requires beta-review; for inner testing -
   just processing, but you have to add inner testers as team members
3. No way